# SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context) returns null

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm having a bit of trouble with creating a provider hosted app for SharePoint Online.
The idea behind this app is to have multiple parts within it to achieve different pieces of functionality. I have developed a "Requests" page which works really well and interacts with SharePoint as expected, however, I have now gone onto creating another one.

I added an new Web Form to the Pages folder in the solution explorer and began to develop my page as before, however, the code behind fails on getting the client context. Upon further debugging, I found that it is the SPHostUrl that returns null, but I am unsure as to why this would be causing an issue. Does SharePoint have issues with apps that contain multiple web forms?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: It seems as though the url is not passing through at all, thus not picking up the SPHostUrl value from there. Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that on the first request the SharePoint context is initialized correctly. This is for example done in the `SharePointContextFilter` with the `SharePointContextProvider.CheckRedirectStatus` call.

The `SharePointContext` class requires certain parameters to be passed as query parameter or as form data. `SharePointContext` will store these values in cookies for further calls. If you initialize `SharePointContext` in the first web form, where all required information is available, you should be able to use `SharePointContext` on further pages, even if not all information is passed in the url.